# Does LUKS take space?

Tags: disk-usage, encryption, luks

I have just encrypted an empty partition using LUKS. The partition size is 875 GiB.

Before encryption 28 KiB were in use. After encryption, 14.81 GiB are in use (1.7% of the total).

Why is that so? Does the encryption take disk space?

Answer (score 4):

LUKS has a header with a certain size, for LUKS 1 the default is 2 MiB, for LUKS 2 it's 16 MiB.

For LUKS 2 there is also a different mode that adds integrity checksums to the block device, which would take up additional space. But this is exotic and not in widespread use yet.

So if you see 14GB in use, like in `df -h`, that's unrelated to LUKS. It's a filesystem thing.

It may be indirectly related, as various flavors of `mkfs` pick default values depending on which device you want formatted, so some filesystem tool might be using different defaults for a LUKS encrypted device, resulting in such a perceived change.

Even then, you'd still have to look into the filesystem, since LUKS is not directly involved. If LUKS takes up space, it's the total size of the encrypted device that shrinks instead - it will be 2MiB or 16MiB smaller than the backing device, and with integrity that difference would be even larger.

Answer (score 0):

I short: yes it does.

The reason for it, is LUKS puts most of parts and tools required for its operation on the disk it encrypts.

Details are in the [LUKS1 On-Disk Format Specification](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf) *(PDF)*. It even contains a set of short examples in C.